# Connect Mac to closer Access Point

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi

this is a complicated question that I think has an super easy answer but I've been googling and no success so far.

What happens is that I use my Mac in the office, and the office has three floors. Look at the crappy drawing of the floor distribution.

```
         |FLOOR-X |
         |Elevator|

 [AP1]   |   WC   |    [AP2]
```

All the floors are the same.

What happen is that I'm in the second floor at the farest point from AP2... And my Mac tries (or successfully)to connect to the AP on the floor above (which is closer). This of course, makes my pings take a lot of time and a lot of lost packets. The AP from the floor above is closer in distance, but because of the walls, floor, etc. The noise is worst.

IT guys in here made a "costly" solution by adding a new AP with different SSID in the middle between ME and the AP2 (the one on my floor). This of course fixes the problem, but It's not the optimal way. And it's also a waste of APs.

I'm looking for some way to tweak the Mac Hardware or something like that to connect to the desired one. Any ideas?

Comment: Open network in sys preferences then advanced, now move the wanted AP to the top of the list. If you still have problem -  Delete the unwanted AP from your list (don't worry you can get it back if you want to)

Comment: Mmmm no. That's not the solution because the X number of APs in all the building's floors broadcast the same three different SSIDs. Makes sense?

Comment: Three different SSIDs or three exactly-the-same SSIDs? If they're different SSIDs, then I'd say the same thing as Buscar. If they're the same, it's a far more interesting problem with no obvious suggestions I can give.

Comment: Imagine X number of AP distributed around the whole building. Each one of them broadcasts three differnets SSIDs. AP1 broadcasts: WLAN1, WLAn2, WLANGuests. AP2: WLAN1, WLAN2 and WLANGuests. AP3... and so on ... That's the thing. So my mac instead of connecting to closest AP, connects to the one on the upper level.

Comment: @villancikos did you ever figure out a way to fix this?

Comment: @arturomp no my friend! unfortunately no that I can remember.